# Hide first n elements by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There is a list of divs in my HTML page having the same class attribute.

```
<div class="card"></div>
.
.
<div class="card"></div>
```

Now, all these divs have been initially set as hidden elements in JavaScript:
**$ (".card").hide();**

Then, there is a loop required on all of these divs which will make only some of them visible for which I wrote:

```
var i =0;
$('.card').each(function(i1,obj) {
   if(i<5){
          $(obj).show();
          //$(this).find('card').show();//tried this also
   }
   i = i+1;
 });
```

But, still, no element is shown on the HTML page.Please suggest what is wrong in this implementation.

Comment: You're already in the class .card why are you trying to find .card again inside the function? if you just do `$(this).show();` it should work

Comment: it is what I also tried apart from the line just above it,but the $(obj) line also doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Do you only want to show top 5 `.card` in DOM?

Comment: yes that is the case

Comment: @AbhishekPandey 5 I would guess, starts at 0

Comment: @user5014677,it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try `$('.card:lt(5)').show()`

Comment: @Tushar excellent, never seen that before! That is the answer to use

Comment: There was a typo in the code. You had used `i1` instead of `i`. If that was there in the original code, that could have been the issue.

Comment: No,it is not a typo,i1 would also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

All `$ (".card").hide();` does is: it sets the inline style to `display: none;`. To overwrite `inline-styles` you can use the CSS `important!` keyword and use [:nth-child(-n+6)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) like:

```
.card:nth-child(-n+6){ /* (-n+6) => will show the first 5 items */
    display:block !important;
}
```

See full running working code snippet

```js
$ (".card").hide();
```

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 5px;
}

.card:nth-child(-n+6){
    display:block !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">1</div>
<div class="card">2</div>
<div class="card">3</div>
<div class="card">4</div>
<div class="card">5</div>
<div class="card">6</div>
<div class="card">7</div>
<div class="card">8</div>
<div class="card">9</div>
```

**-- old answer --**

To show the `<div>`s in the iteration use `$(this)`!

Then the index in the each you passed `i1` so you need to use `i1` . . .

There is no reason in this case to define `var i`

```js
$('.card').each(function(i1,obj) {
   if(i1 < 5){
      $(this).show();
   }
 });
```

```css
.card {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 5px;
  
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">1</div>
<div class="card">2</div>
<div class="card">3</div>
<div class="card">4</div>
<div class="card">5</div>
<div class="card">6</div>
<div class="card">7</div>
<div class="card">8</div>
<div class="card">9</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative is to use [javascript `.slice()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
$(".card").slice(0, 5).show(); /* start at index 0 and show while less than 5 */
```

This gives the added benefit that you can adjust the starting position if you want to show different elements e.g. `$(".card").slice(3, 8).show();`

```js
for (let i=0; i<10; i++) {
  $('body').append(`<div class="card">${i+1}</div>`);
}

$(".card").slice(0, 5).show(); /* start at index 0 and show while less than 5 */
```

```css
.card {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`:lt()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/). It accepts the zero-based index.

```
$('.card:lt(5)').show();
```

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $('body').append(`<div class="card">${i + 1}</div>`);
}

$('.card:lt(5)').show();
```

```css
.card {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**HTML PART**

```
<div class="card" id="card1"></div>
<div class="card" id="card2"></div>
.
.
<div class="card" id="cardn"></div>
```

**jquery Part**

```
$('.card').each(function(i1,obj) {
   if(i<5){
         $("#card"+i).show();
   }
   i++;
 });
```

Comment: there are too many divs,would be cumbersome to assign id to all of them.

Comment: You can assign id  dynamically